# Visual studio XML comment for generics

Tags: c#, generics, xml-comments

How can I write this in a proper way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides extension methods for <see cref="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"/> matrix.
/// </summary>
public static class DictonaryMatExtensions
{...}
```

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` part is bothering me.

Comment: It is bothering you because..?

Comment: I want to build a documentation, and VS complaints that the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary ca not be resolved.

Comment: It is not bothering you, but the compiler.

Comment: OK, what is the proper way to write System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary so the compiler does not complain ?

Comment: You are correct, this is a problem because for example with a class `Foo<T>` my compiler produces `warning CS1574: XML comment on ... has cref attribute 'Foo' that could not be resolved`. Is this same same warning # you get?

Comment: Yes, it is the same warning. I am just looking the proper way how to reference generic classes so I can build a documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `{` and `}` to represent the generic parameter(s)

```
/// ... <see cref="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> matrix.
```